# Filtering a list of lists for sublists with specific content

Tags: python

Currently I am attempting to filter a 2D list that has 52:3 dimensions. I want to filter the list based on the rows.

Example rows for the input list are:

```
list = [[u'Kr', u'Se', ''],[u'Fe', '', ''],[u'Ca', '', '']]
```

The output from the list filtering needs to be when there are two spaces ('') present in the row. It needs to keep that row and place the row into a new variable. Therefore the example output would be:

```
new = [[u'Fe', '', ''],[u'Ca', '', '']]
```

Comment: Hey, did you get it to work? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

Don't use the variable name `list`, because you will shadow the built in list.

You have a list of lists here, and some of those lists contain the empty string `''`, not a space, which would be `' '`.

That being said, you can count how many empty strings any sublist `x` contains, and if that count is equal to two, put them into a new list with the help of a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [[u'Kr', u'Se', ''],[u'Fe', '', ''],[u'Ca', '', '']]
>>> result = [x for x in lst if x.count('') == 2]
>>> result
[[u'Fe', '', ''], [u'Ca', '', '']]
```

Note that since we did not copy anything here, changes to the sublists will be seen across all references/names for them:

```
>>> result[0][0] = 'Xe'
>>> result
[['Xe', '', ''], [u'Ca', '', '']]
>>> lst
[[u'Kr', u'Se', ''], ['Xe', '', ''], [u'Ca', '', '']]
```

If this behavior is not desired, create copies of your lists in the list comprehension (the only difference to the previous example is the usage of `x[:]` instead of `x`):

```
>>> lst = [[u'Kr', u'Se', ''],[u'Fe', '', ''],[u'Ca', '', '']]
>>> result = [x[:] for x in lst if x.count('') == 2]
>>> result
[[u'Fe', '', ''], [u'Ca', '', '']]
>>> result[0][0] = 'Xe'
>>> result
[['Xe', '', ''], [u'Ca', '', '']]
>>> lst
[[u'Kr', u'Se', ''], [u'Fe', '', ''], [u'Ca', '', '']]
```